# Two tables with linking column "id" that return only unique "id" lines for the parent table

Tags: sql

I have two tables.  One that keeps all of my threads started on a subject and another that keeps all the posts that related to each thread.  They are both using the "id" columns for relation purposes.  For example the very first thread (AKA subject) opened up has three comments total on it including the original post.  For this example I have taken the irrelevant columns and named them consecutive column names such as col1-col6.  I do still need all of these columns returned in the query results though!

**table - dbo.Threads** (parent table)

```
id  col1  timestamp                col2  col3  col4  col5  subject
1   6     2011-11-07 14:52:08.650  6     NULL  3     0     Request 1 blah blue
2   7     2011-11-07 14:53:01.410  6     NULL  2     0     Request 2 blah green
3   6     2011-11-07 14:54:01.453  6     NULL  3     0     Request 3 blah red
4   7     2011-11-08 10:50:57.440  6     NULL  3     0     Request 4 blah black
```

**table - dbo.Posts** (child table)

```
id  timestamp                  col6  post
1   2011-11-07 14:52:08.710    3     This is the 1st orange post for one
2   2011-11-07 14:53:01.420    3     This is the 1st green post for two
3   2011-11-07 14:54:01.463    3     This is the 1st blue post for three
1   2011-11-08 15:08:59.707    3     This is the 2nd red post for one
1   2011-11-09 15:09:16.333    3     This is the 3rd black post for one
4   2011-11-08 10:50:57.527    3     This is the 1st yellow post for four
```

Currently I have tried using the following query just for testing...

```
"SELECT Threads.*, Posts.* FROM Threads INNER JOIN Posts ON Threads.id = Posts.id ORDER BY Posts.timestamp"
```

This returns the following...

```
id  col1  timestamp                col2  col3  col4  col5  subject               id  timestamp                col6  post
1   6     2011-11-07 14:52:08.650  6     NULL  3     0     Request 1 blah blue   1   2011-11-07 14:52:08.710  3     This is the 1st orange post for one
2   7     2011-11-07 14:53:01.410  6     NULL  2     0     Request 2 blah green  2   2011-11-07 14:53:01.420  3     This is the 1st green post for two
3   6     2011-11-07 14:54:01.453  6     NULL  3     0     Request 3 blah red    3   2011-11-07 14:54:01.463  3     This is the 1st blue post for three
4   7     2011-11-08 10:50:57.440  6     NULL  3     0     Request 4 blah black  4   2011-11-08 10:50:57.527  3     This is the 1st yellow post for four
1   6     2011-11-07 14:52:08.650  6     NULL  3     0     Request 1 blah blue   1   2011-11-08 15:08:59.707  3     This is the 2nd red post for one
1   6     2011-11-07 14:52:08.650  6     NULL  3     0     Request 1 blah blue   1   2011-11-09 15:09:16.333  3     This is the 3rd black post for one
```

I need to have a query that will search both the dbo.Threads.subject column and the dbo.Posts.post column for a text crietera.  In this example I will use "blue".  Currently I have tried using the following query...

```
"SELECT Threads.*, Posts.* FROM Threads INNER JOIN Posts ON Threads.id = Posts.id WHERE ((Threads.subject LIKE '%blue%') OR (Posts.post LIKE '%blue%')) ORDER BY Posts.timestamp"
```

This returns the following...

```
id  col1  timestamp                col2  col3  col4  col5  subject              id  timestamp                col6  post
1   6     2011-11-07 14:52:08.650  6     NULL  3     0     Request 1 blah blue  1   2011-11-07 14:52:08.710  3     This is the 1st orange post for one
3   6     2011-11-07 14:54:01.453  6     NULL  3     0     Request 3 blah red   3   2011-11-07 14:54:01.463  3     This is the 1st blue post for three
1   6     2011-11-07 14:52:08.650  6     NULL  3     0     Request 1 blah blue  1   2011-11-08 15:08:59.707  3     This is the 2nd red post for one
1   6     2011-11-07 14:52:08.650  6     NULL  3     0     Request 1 blah blue  1   2011-11-09 15:09:16.333  3     This is the 3rd black post for one
```

That is ALMOST exactly what I needed as the results...  I currently need it to return the same exact results but without the last two lines.  I only want unique id's returned.  In this case I do not want three results for id "1" to be returned, I only want one result for "1" to be returned and then of course one results returned for "3" giving me the following results...

```
id  col1  timestamp                col2  col3  col4  col5  subject              id  timestamp                col6  post
1   6     2011-11-07 14:52:08.650  6     NULL  3     0     Request 1 blah blue  1   2011-11-07 14:52:08.710  3     This is the 1st orange post for one
3   6     2011-11-07 14:54:01.453  6     NULL  3     0     Request 3 blah red   3   2011-11-07 14:54:01.463  3     This is the 1st blue post for three
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you want the earliest entry from the posts table?  If so, a subselect first getting all the earliest IDs for a given thread seems like it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT T.*, P.* 
FROM Threads 
INNER JOIN POSTS P ON T.id = P.id 
WHERE ((T.subject LIKE '%blue%') OR (P.post LIKE '%blue%')) 
AND P.Timestamp = (Select min(P2.timestamp) from posts P2 where ID = T.ID) 
ORDER BY P.timestamp
```

--The and statement here is intended to get the earliest timestamp for the Thread.ID

Comment: OK so I had to alter a few things for it to work right.  For example I had to do the following... (1)Add "T" on line 2 (2)Changed "POSTS" to "Posts" on line 3 (3)Changed "P.Timestamp" to "P.timestamp" on line 5 (4)Changed "posts P2" to "Posts P2" on line 5

Answer (score 1):

One way;

```
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.id, T.timestamp, T.subject,
        P.id as POST_ID, P.timestamp as POST_TIMESTAMP, P.post,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.id ORDER BY T.id, P.timestamp) AS ROWNUM
    FROM 
        Threads as T INNER JOIN Posts AS P ON (T.id = P.id)
    WHERE
        T.subject LIKE '%blue%' OR P.post LIKE '%blue%'
 ) X
    WHERE X.ROWNUM = 1
```

Here we partition by the unique id generating an ordinal row number for each one based on the order of the thread id and the timestamp of the post.

Comment: BTW you need to alias a column if its name is in both tables a la `P.id as POST_ID`

Comment: This works very well too!  The only difference is that with this query I did not retain all my columns because Alex used things like T.id, T.timestamp rather than T.* :)